# Why is the camera going inside my mesh, when the camera is not inside?

Tags: camera

I found an answer to a problem, and I thought it would be good to post.  I was having a problem where when I hit ctrl-alt-0, Instead of going to the view of the camera, it would go inside a mesh itself.  I did not have any hidden cameras either.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this problem is simple.  Blender has a feature where you can select an object, hit ctrl-0, and that object becomes the "camera."  Thus, the camera view was inside my object.  This is pretty neat!  I'm not sure how to use it in a beneficial way, but it must be good for something.
If you want to set the camera view back to your original camera, select your camera and hit ctrl-0.

Comment: This is just what Ctrl 0 does in Blender 2.79

Comment: really?  I didn't know it did that.  Apparently, I never tried to change the main camera while one of my objects was selected.  I can edit my answer.

Comment: My guess is that there will be times when you want to know whether one object is in direct line of sight of another object, even if neither object is a camera. So an object-as-camera function would be one way to determine that.

Comment: That's a good point, R-800!  That might be a useful way to find out if someone is looking at another person, say if they were in the hallway next to the room that the first guy is in.